# stacks with strings and integers - C

Tags: c

[3rd update]
I made some changes to David's code. I changed: `n->next = s->top;s->top = n;` to `n->next = NULL;s->top = n;` like H.S. suggested; and also added different features to the main function. I'm trying to get the char name and int value as input from the user while the program is running. The program should keep taking data from the user, storing it in the stack and allocating memory accordingly. The program only ends when the user types 'end' (char) or 0 (int). The code gets compiled, but that's it, after that, any input and the program stops. Also, am I wasting memory using `fgets(str,20,stdin)`? What if I don't use all that size. Any feedback is very much appreciated!

```
///PROGRAM STRUCTURE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack_node{
    int value;
    char *name;
    struct stack_node * next;
};
typedef struct stack_node stack_node;

struct stack{
    stack_node *top;
    int size;
};
typedef struct stack stack;

stack *create_stack()
{
    stack *s = malloc (sizeof *s);
    if (!s) {
        perror ("malloc-s");
        return NULL;
    }

    s->size = 0;
    s->top = NULL;

    return s;
}

int empty_stack (stack * s) {
    return s->size == 0;
}


stack_node *push_stack (stack *s, int value, char *name) /// ****
{
    stack_node *n = malloc (sizeof *n);
    if (!n) {
        perror ("malloc-n");
        return NULL;
    }

    n->value = value;
    n->name = malloc (strlen (name) + 1);
    if (!n->name) {
        perror ("malloc-name");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (n->name, name);
    n->next = NULL; /// ****
    s->top = n;
    s->size++;

    return n;
}

stack_node *pop_stack (stack *s)
{
    if (s->size > 0) {
        stack_node *node = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->next;
        s->size--;
        return node;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void free_node (stack_node *n)
{
    if (n->name)
        free (n->name);

    free (n);
}

void free_stack (stack *s)
{
    while (s->size > 0) {
        stack_node *victim = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->next;
        free_node (victim);
        s->size--;
    }

    free (s);
}

int main (void) {

    stack *s = create_stack();
    stack_node *node = NULL;

    char *str; ///NAME
    int vs; ///VALUE
    int i=0;

    if (!s)
        return 1;

    do{
        printf("NAME{%d]: ",i);
        fgets(str,20,stdin); ///***?
        printf("VALUE[%d]: ",i);
        scanf(" %d",&vs);
        if (push_stack (s, vs, str) == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: push node failed '%d'.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }while(str != 'end' || vs != 0);
   i=0;

    while ((node = pop_stack(s)) != NULL) {
        printf ("value[%d]:  %d    name[%d]: %s\n", i,node->value, i,node->name);
        i++;
        free_node (node);
    }
    free_stack (s);

    return 0;
}

///**********
    do{
        printf("NAME[%d]: ",i);

        if(fgets(buf,sizeof buf,stdin)){
        int rtn = sscanf (buf, "%63[^\n]", name);
        if(rtn == 1){
            printf("VALUE[%d]: ",i);
            scanf(" %d",&vs);

        }
        }
        push_stack(s,vs,name);
        if (s == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: push node failed '%d'.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }while(node->name != "end" || node->value != 0);
```

Comment: You could make the data portion of your stack_node a `void *` and malloc it as you please.

Comment: Well could declare a new `struct` with `char*` for name and `int value`. Than change stack_node to use your new struct instead of an int. Which was basically what you already mentioned, That should be possible, to keep it simple don't make it a pointer but use a plain struct.

Comment: I tried both ways....but I'm either not storing it properly in the stack or displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. It's obvious you have put effort into your code, but it is also obvious you are still struggling to wrap your head around storing a struct as a node within the stack (and with basic string handling issues).

First, there is no need to cast the return of malloc, see See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Next, always size your allocation for an object based on the *derefernced pointer* to the object. For example `stack *s` declares `s` as a pointer to type `stack`. If `s` is a *pointer to* `stack`, then `*s` is type `stack`. Sizing your allocations with the actual pointer itself with eliminate any chance of an incorrect size. Further, it is your responsibility to **validate** every allocation by checking the return is not `NULL`. With that, your `create_stack()` could be:

```
stack *create_stack()
{
    stack *s = malloc (sizeof *s);  /* size from dereferenced pointer */
    if (!s) {                       /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-s");
        return NULL;
    }

    s->size = 0;
    s->top = NULL;

    return s;
}
```

Your `empty_stack` is unused, but otherwise OK.

Your `push_stack` function is where a number of problems lie. First you cannot allocate for the node and the string at the same time! (even if you could, you would be one-byte too small as you have forgotten space for the *nul-terminating* character at the end of the string). You declare:

```
struct stack_node{
    int value;
    char *name;
    struct stack_node * next;
};
```

You must allocate first for your node, *then* allocate storage for your pointer `name` -- remembering to **validate** the allocation as done in `create_stack()`, e.g.

```
    stack_node *n = malloc (sizeof *n); /* allocate node only */
    if (!n) {                           /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-n");
        return NULL;
    }

    n->value = value;
    n->name = malloc (strlen (name) + 1);   /* allocate strlen + 1 chars */
    if (!n->name) {                         /* validate! */
        perror ("malloc-name");
        return NULL;
    }
```

Next, you *cannot* assign strings in C (aside from initialization of a pointer to point to a *string-literal*, e.g. `char *name = "foo";`) In C, you must copy your string to the valid storage your create for `n->name`. For example:

```
    strcpy (n->name, name);     /* you cannot assign strings, use strcpy */
```

Further, how are you going to indicate to the caller, whether your allocations succeeded or failed if you declare `push_stack` as type `void`??

Always select a return type that can indicate success/failure where required. With that in mind, you can simply return a pointer to the new node (which is convenient for immediate use anyway), or return `NULL` on failure, e.g.

```
/* choose return type that can indicate success/failure */
stack_node *push_stack (stack *s, int value, const char *name)
{
    stack_node *n = malloc (sizeof *n); /* allocate node only */
    if (!n) {                           /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-n");
        return NULL;
    }

    n->value = value;
    n->name = malloc (strlen (name) + 1);   /* allocate strlen + 1 chars */
    if (!n->name) {                         /* validate! */
        perror ("malloc-name");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (n->name, name);     /* you cannot assign strings, use strcpy */
    n->next = s->top;
    s->top = n;
    s->size++;

    return n;
}
```

You do not want two-separate `pop` function. Instead of `pop_stack_value` and `pop_stack_name`, you simply want a `pop_stack` that returns a pointer to the top node. You can then access either the value or name (e.g. `node->value` or `node->name`) as required.

It also makes sense to declare a couple of simple helper functions to free the memory allocated when it is no longer needed. You are dealing with nodes and the stack, so a `free_node` helper and a `free_stack` helper make sense. (and remember, you may want to free the stack before it is empty, so code the `free_stack` accordingly), e.g.

```
void free_node (stack_node *n)  /* free node helper function */
{
    if (n->name)
        free (n->name);

    free (n);
}

void free_stack (stack *s)      /* free stack helper (need not be empty) */
{
    while (s->size > 0) {
        stack_node *victim = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->next;
        free_node (victim);
        s->size--;
    }

    free (s);
}
```

Putting all the pieces together in a short example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack_node{
    int value;
    char *name;
    struct stack_node * next;
};
typedef struct stack_node stack_node;

struct stack{
    stack_node *top;
    int size;
};
typedef struct stack stack;

stack *create_stack()
{
    stack *s = malloc (sizeof *s);  /* size from dereferenced pointer */
    if (!s) {                       /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-s");
        return NULL;
    }

    s->size = 0;
    s->top = NULL;

    return s;
}

int empty_stack (stack * s) {       /* s->size is type 'int' */
    return s->size == 0;
}

/* choose return type that can indicate success/failure */
stack_node *push_stack (stack *s, int value, const char *name)
{
    stack_node *n = malloc (sizeof *n); /* allocate node only */
    if (!n) {                           /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-n");
        return NULL;
    }

    n->value = value;
    n->name = malloc (strlen (name) + 1);   /* allocate strlen + 1 chars */
    if (!n->name) {                         /* validate! */
        perror ("malloc-name");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (n->name, name);     /* you cannot assign strings, use strcpy */
    n->next = s->top;
    s->top = n;
    s->size++;

    return n;
}

stack_node *pop_stack (stack *s)    /* return the node on pop */
{
    if (s->size > 0) {
        stack_node *node = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->next;
        s->size--;
        return node;    /* caller is responsible for freeing node */
    }

    return NULL;
}

void free_node (stack_node *n)  /* free node helper function */
{
    if (n->name)
        free (n->name);

    free (n);
}

void free_stack (stack *s)      /* free stack helper (need not be empty) */
{
    while (s->size > 0) {
        stack_node *victim = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->next;
        free_node (victim);
        s->size--;
    }

    free (s);
}

int main (void) {

    const char *str[] = { "john", "jack", "jill", "sally", "sue" };
    int n = sizeof str/sizeof *str;
    stack *s = create_stack();
    stack_node *node = NULL;

    if (!s)         /* validate !!! */
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (push_stack (s, i+1, str[i]) == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: push node failed '%d'.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }

    while ((node = pop_stack(s)) != NULL) {
        printf ("value:  %2d    name: %s\n", node->value, node->name);
        free_node (node);   /* free node */
    }
    free_stack (s);     /* free stack */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stack_struct
value:   5    name: sue
value:   4    name: sally
value:   3    name: jill
value:   2    name: jack
value:   1    name: john
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/stack_struct
==4204== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4204== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4204== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4204== Command: ./bin/stack_struct
==4204==
value:   5    name: sue
value:   4    name: sally
value:   3    name: jill
value:   2    name: jack
value:   1    name: john
==4204==
==4204== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4204==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4204==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 161 bytes allocated
==4204==
==4204== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4204==
==4204== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4204== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Finally, to avoid most of these problems to begin with, always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` or `clang` compile string. (add `-pedantic` for several additional warnings). For `clang`, instead you can use `-Weverything`. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windoze), add `/W3` (or use `/Wall` but you will get quite a few extraneous windows non-code related warnings). Read and understand each warning. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur.

You can learn as much about coding by simply listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from most tutorials.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Taking `value` Input, then `name`**

When you take user input, consider using `fgets` for reading both the name and value (and then use `sscanf` (or `strtol`) to convert to `int`). You avoid many pitfalls with `scanf` and failure to empty `stdin` after a *matching failure* (which will generally lead to an infinite loop as well as *Undefined Behavior*)

You purposely want to loop continually until you validate your have the input you ask for -- and that it meets your requirements (range, etc...). You also must protect against the user canceling input by generating a manual `EOF` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze, but see: [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/))

```
/* if you need constants, #define one (or more), or use a global enum */
#define MAXC    1024    /* max chars for input buffer (don't skimp) */
#define MAXNM     64    /* max length for name buffer (ditto) */
...
int main (void) {

    stack *s = create_stack();
    stack_node *node = NULL;

    if (!s)         /* validate !!! */
        return 1;

    for (;;) {      /* loop continually taking input until exit conditon */
        char buf[MAXC]  = "",   /* line buffer for fgets */
            name[MAXNM] = "";   /* buffer for parsing name from line */
        int value = 0;          /* int to parse from line */

        for (;;) {  /* loop continually until you get valid int */
            fputs ("\nenter value: ", stdout);  /* prompt for value */
            if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {     /* validate line read */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &value) == 1) { /* convert to int */
                    if (value == 0) {   /* your exit condition */
                        fputs ("  value == 0 (input done)\n", stderr );
                        goto inputdone; /* jump out of both loops */
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else    /* non-integer (non-numeric) input */
                    fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            }
            else {  /* fgets returned EOF (user canceled) */
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                goto inputdone; /* jump out of both loops */
            }
        }

        for (;;) {      /* loop continually until name recieved */
            fputs ("enter name : ", stdout);        /* prompt name */
            if (fgets (name, MAXNM, stdin)) {       /* read name */
                size_t len = strlen (name);         /* get length */
                if (len && name[len-1] == '\n') {   /* last char \n ? */
                    name[--len] = 0;                /* overwrite with \0 */
                    if (len)                    /* check 1 char remains */
                        break;                  /* got good name, go push */
                    else    /* user just pressed [Enter] */
                        fputs ("  error: empty-line.\n", stderr);
                }
                else if (len == MAXNM -1)   /* was input too long? */
                    fputs ("  warning: name truncated.\n", stderr);
            }
            else {  /* fgets returned EOF (user canceled) */
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                goto inputdone; /* jump out of both loops */
            }
        }

        push_stack (s, value, name);    /* push value and name on stack */
    }
    inputdone:;

    puts ("\nvalues stored in stack\n");
    while ((node = pop_stack(s)) != NULL) {
        printf ("value:  %2d    name: %s\n", node->value, node->name);
        free_node (node);   /* free node */
    }
    free_stack (s);     /* free stack */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** it would probably be better to end input when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line rather than looking for a `value == 0` (because an `int` can be zero))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stack_struct_input_simple

enter value: 1
enter name : Frank Zappa

enter value: 2
enter name :
error: empty-line.
enter name : Jimmy Buffet

enter value: 3
enter name : Grahm Nash

enter value: 4
enter name : John Bonham

enter value: 0
value == 0 (input done)

values stored in stack

value:   4    name: John Bonham
value:   3    name: Grahm Nash
value:   2    name: Jimmy Buffet
value:   1    name: Frank Zappa
```

See if you can go though the input routine above and understand why it is written the way it is. (I also have one that will accept both `value name` or `value` then `name`) You can be as flexible as you want with input as long as you follow the rules and **validate** everything, protect against a manual `EOF` and always know what remains in your input buffer (e.g. `stdin`).

Comment: Thank you so much, David! You just blew my mind with all this info, it was exactly what I was looking for. I do have a few questions:  - how would I make the value input independent of the name input? - and how could I change the main function to get the name/value input from the user while the program is running instead of declaring name and/or value in my code?   ////  INPUT: value[0]: 34 name[0]: John // value[1]:21 name[1]:Jack // value[2]:99 name[2]: Jill ///// OUTPUT: value[0]:99 name[0]:Jill // value[1]:21 name[1]:Jack // value[3]: 34 name[3]: John

Comment: The program will ask for value[0], and only then ask for name[0]...repeating this process with value[1], name[1].. and so on, until the user enters the value zero, which ends the program. And all the input gets stored in the stack.

Comment: @tylerdurden - to make the value independent of the name input, you would just use a temporary instance of your `struct_node`. After you create it, you are free to fill either `value` or `name` at your leisure. Either as part of `push` or in a separate function, just check that you have both `value` and `name` before pushing it onto the stack. You are also free to push with only a `value` or `name`, then on `pop` (or before use), you can check to see which value you have available -- completely up to you.

Comment: @tylerdurden User input can be with either `fgets/sscanf` (recommended) or simply with `scanf` (which has pitfalls for the new programmer). If your max input could be `128` chars, declare a buffer with `256` chars (don't skimp) and read a line of input from the user with `fgets` (e.g. `int v = 0; char buf[256] = "", name[64] = "";` ... `if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { int rtn = sscanf (buf, "%d %63[^\n]", &v, name); if (rtn == 2) { /* fill both value/name */ } else if (rtn == 1) { /* fill value * } else { /* error: get next line */ }` There are many variations.

Comment: @tylerdurden - try and work that out. If you run into problems, I can add an input routine. If you think about it, you can just use your `else if` case to check if `v == 0` to end -- or add a beginning case to the `if` to check `if (rtn == EOF)` to end as well (you can also just check if `*buf` (e.g. `buf[0]`) is equal to `'\n'` indicating the user just hit return on an empty line to end as well (many ways to skin that cat....)

Comment: I just edited my question. Right bellow the code you can see the way I'm trying to store data. is it okay to use char name[64] = "" to push_stack(s,vs,name); like that since char name isn't a pointer? Also, what happens to the memory buf[256] and name[64] if I don't use it all?

Comment: Sure, that's fine -- why? -- because an array is converted to a pointer to the first element on access (with a couple of exceptions not relevant here). So you are passing a pointer `:)`

Comment: I coded in such a way that it's only possible to push data to the stack once you have both value and name. Anyways, after the first name input and value input the program stops.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to do it -- but you should be SHOT for not **validating the return** of `scanf` `:)`. I'll add an example for you to compare with.

Comment: I just fixed it. Now I get the error message saying my  scanf for the int value didn't work lol. I just don't get why..

Comment: Give me a second and I'll look at why. Duh... `char *str;` declares an *Uninitialized Pointer* that points to some indeterminate memory address where you do not have the ability to write to. `fgets(str,20,stdin);` invokes *Undefined Behavior* -- your dead!. Look at the constants I declare `MAXC, MAXNM` and how I use them to make sure I have valid storage to hold the input I take `:)`

Comment: I totally agree with you: user pressing Enter on an empty line rather than looking for a value == 0 is a much better way to end the program. I just didn't thought about that possibility...I'll internalize all the info above and then I'll try to change that.

Comment: I only have one last question: you said not to save on space when using MAXC and MAXNM, but what happens with the idle space that doesn't get used during/after the program runs? Does the free_node() and free_stack() solve that? I know my pc isn't gonna feel the difference, but I'm always thinking on the possibility of this code running on a microcontroller, for exemple, that doesn't have a lot of spare memory.

Comment: Recall, when `fgets` fills a buffer it *nul-terminates* the buffer making it a valid string (e.g. it places ASCII `'\0'` (numeric `0`) as the final character). That is how string functions know when to stop reading (e.g. `strcpy`, etc...), they read until they encounter the *nul-terminating* character. To exit with `[Enter]` on an empty line, just test if the 1st character in the buffer filled by `fgets` is `'\n'` (e.g. `fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin); if (*buf == '\n') { /* empty-line, exit */ }`. (`*buf` is the same as `*(buf + 0)` is the same as `buf[0]`)

Comment: As far as the "extra space" in `buf`, etc.. -- it never enters the picture. Recall, in `push_stack` we size the memory for name with `malloc (strlen (name) + 1);`. It doesn't matter if the buffer you pass in as `name` has 1 million characters reserved or `len+1` chars reserved, the `strlen()` of the string in the buffer is the same (so don't skimp on input buffers `:)`

Comment: Also note the basic "stack space" provided for your program (and each function) is between 1-4 Megabytes (generally). (`malloc'ed` memory doesn't count against it), so if you use `1024` chars for `buf`, its 1% or less. Your PC doesn't care at all. The only time your computer would care is if your automatic storage variable exceeds the stack space (then you have StackOverflow). You will generally only get there declaring large 2D arrays on the stack (e.g. `int arr[1024][1024];` would do it with a 1M stack)

Comment: Got it !! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to alter your `stack_node` struct to directly include the name.

```
struct stack_node{
    int value;
    struct stack_node * next;
    char name[1];
};
```

This particular form has the advantage that if you call `malloc` as follows:

```
struct stack_node * new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node + strlen(name));
```

you get exactly the correct amount of memory, including space for the trailing `NUL` byte on the string.

Ob warning.  Skip the last paragraph if you are humor impaired.

Still here?  Good.  Failing all this, you could always try a [Soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) interface.  But then perhaps we should never talk about that. ;)

Comment: I made some changes to the program and it's working without any compilation errors, but I still can't display the char name :/

Comment: The way you're trying to save name in `push_stack()` isn't correct.  If you call `malloc()` like that, the first thing you need to do is add 1 to allow space for the 'NUL' byte that ends the string.  Then you need to point `n->name ` at the space immediately after the node addressed by `n`, so it's looking into the "extra" memory you grabbed during the `malloc()` call.  Finally, you need to copy the string to that location with `strncpy()`. ...

Comment: ...  As a general rule of thumb, it's always a good habit to be in to use `strncpy()` rather than `strcpy()` since doing so will dramatically reduce your risk of a buffer overrun if you get handed bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Few of problems in your code:

Problem 1:
Look at these statement of function `push_stack()`:

```
    n->next = s->top;
    s->top = n;
```

The `next` of stack node `n` is pointing to `top` of `stack` and `top` of stack is pointing back to node `n`. The `next` of the node created should be `NULL` as it will be top node of stack. You don't need this statement `n->next = s->top;`. It should be:

```
    n->next = NULL;
    s->top = n;
```

Problem 2:

In `main()`, you are doing:

```
    printf("STACK: %d \n",pop_stack_value(s));
    printf("STACK: %s \n", pop_stack_name(s));
```

and in function `pop_stack_value()`, you are doing:

```
    stack_node * sn = s->top;
    s->top = s->top->next;
    free(sn);
```

`s->top` is pointing to the `top` of stack and the `top` of stack is pointing back to node (as you did in `push_stack()`). The `free(sn)` will free the top of stack. Now in function `pop_stack_name()`, you are doing

```
    char * name = s->top->name;
    stack_node * sn = s->top;
    s->top = s->top->next;
    s->size--;
    free(sn);
```

`s->top` is pointing to memory which has been already freed in `pop_stack_value()` and you are trying to access memory which your program doesn't own. This is undefined behavior.

The way you are doing pop operation is completely wrong. In the pop operation of stack, you should pop the whole node instead of popping individual value of node. Once the node is popped, set the `top` of stack to point to the previous node. For that you need to traverse the whole list because you are using singly linked list. As an alternative, you can have doubly linked list in which every node is having its previous node address. With this resetting top of stack would not be an expensive operation.

Comment: He with also need to alloc `(strlen(name) + 1);`  (note: the **+1**) But he cannot allocate for both the struct and `name` at the same time. He also cannot assign `n->name = name;`, but instead will need to alloc `name` separately and `strcpy` after allocation.